# JSF 1.2 DataTable management during view creation

Tags: jsf-1.2

I have a question on how JSF 1.2 manages DataTable exactly. Consider this table (suppose that tableList.persone has 3 items):

```
<h:dataTable id="tablePersone" value="#{tableList.persone}" var="item">   

  <h:column>
    <f:facet name="header">
      <h:outputText value="STATO" />
    </f:facet>
    <h:inputText value="#{item.stato}" />
  </h:column>
  <h:column>
    <f:facet name="header">
      <h:outputText value="CODICE" />
    </f:facet>
    <h:inputText value="#{item.codice}" />
  </h:column>

</h:dataTable>
```

I read that jsf iterates over the items of the list during the render response phase, in fact, "item" is not available when the view is built.

Does it means that jsf does not duplicate the content of the table for each item in the list when creating the tree component?

In the table above, each row has 2 inputText. If jsf does not create a couple of inputText objects for each row, how jsf handles all the 6 request parameters when the form is submitted (in particular during the apply request values phase).

Thanks a lot,

Nico

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong

***Restore View phase*** - in this phase retrieves the component tree for the requested page if it was displayed previously or constructs a new component tree if it is displayed
for the first time. If the page was displayed previously, all components are set
to their prior state. This means that JSF automatically retains form information.
For example, when a user posts illegal data that is rejected during decoding,
the inputs are redisplayed so that the user can correct them.

***Apply Request Values phase***- In this phase, the JSF
implementation iterates over the component objects in the component tree. Each
component object checks which request values belong to it and stores them.

***Process Validations*** phase, the submitted string values are first converted
to “local values,” which can be objects of any type. When you design a JSF
page, you can attach validators that perform correctness checks on the local
values. If validation passes, the JSF life cycle proceeds normally. However,
when conversion or validation errors occur, the JSF implementation invokes
the Render Response phase directly, redisplaying the current page so that the
user has another chance to provide correct inputs.

***Update Model Values phase***- in this phase the
local values are used to update the beans that are wired to the components.

***Invoke Application phase*** the action method of the button or link component
that caused the form submission is executed

***Render Response phase*** - encodes the response and sends it to the
browser.